# What are the steps to Host a REACT App which is using ExpressJS for back-end operations?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, node-modules

I have developed an application which is using REACT for front end and ExpressJS(framework for nodejs) for back-end. Code is running properly in my local machine. 
I have no idea about hosting this application so that other people can use it.

Note: Both REACT project and Node project must be running parallel to make this application work

Appreciate your help !!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Unfortunately, I have to vote to close this as too broad. Asking about off-site resources and recommendations is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) because it tends to attract spam answers and is very broad/opinion-based (there's no correct answer, so it's better suited to a forum free-for-all). But try hosting on [Heroku](https://heroku.com)!

Comment: But this is very important for me to understand. I need to host this app asap

Comment: Are you looking for a platform to host the application or are you asking how to serve your react application using express?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one https://www.heroku.com
It's a popular platform. It's free for a limited amount of space, so it's good to try out applications. It's pretty easy to use, you can even auto-deploy your app every time you push it to github repo, if you have one.

Comment: Sure I will Try that. I have  a confusion that Do I need to host both  REACT and Node part of application separately?